# Format to cleanly save and restore DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to save pandas table in a file, so I can read it from that file later. My requirements:

- the file format should be decently portable (good library support on Windows/Linux in major languages)
- the DataFrame I read should be absolutely identical to the one I saved

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620667/why-is-pandas-read-csv-not-the-reciprocal-of-pandas-dataframe-to-csv), `read_csv` and `to_csv` may work if I provide `index_col=0` argument, but the datatypes are lost (and of course, automatic type inference doesn't guarantee to give me the same types [even for simple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471859/pandas-read-csv-dtype-inference-issue), not to mention if I use python objects like `list`s which are never inferred).

Is there some simple solution that just works for sure, without having to worry about many edge cases?

The only solution I can think of, is using `to_csv` / `read_csv`, but save type information somewhere else. Still, I'm afraid there might more hidden problems (like duplicate column names, etc.).

Comment: @tzaman I guess it's related, but that question is focused on speed, and the top/accepted answer is completely inappropriate in my case since I'm looking for portability. (pickle files can't be read outside of python, not easily).

Comment: That same answer also mentions `hdf5`.  Does that not satisfy?

Comment: @piRSquared Yup just checked and it works. (Apart from same-name columns which are not allowed, but it's ok.) I didn't see any guarantee in the docs that HDF5 read/write are invertible, but I guess it just happens to be..

Comment: I use it regularly.  It's very fast and portable.  Only thing I can't verify is strong support from other languages.  But I do see on wikipedia that it is supported widely.

Comment: @piRSquared yes, definitely perfect solution.

Comment: This is not the same question as the duplicate. It is higher quality. The other question asks for speed, and many answers (including the one answer to this one) aren't portable or were listed as experimental at the time the answer was written. In the interested of ensuring StackOverflow is a useful `key→value`  store, we should probably re-open and properly answer this question. (Unless a *true* and *higher quality* duplicate that predates this question can be found).

Comment: I researched and tested most of the formats supported by pandas. I've prepared markdown for a fairly thorough answer, but won't be able to provide it as an answer as long as this remains locked.

Answer (score -3):

`pd.DataFrame.to_pickle` / `pd.read_pickle` hold columns data types. Let's check it out:

```
df_in.to_pickle('input_5')
df_out = pd.read_pickle('/input_5')
```

Comment: Pickle is a bad choice : it is poorly portable. It evolves between versions of pandas / python.